# how to add a row in existing datatable

Tags: vb.net

In a vb.net Windows Application, I have a datatable wich is not from a database. I want to add a new row, but when I add a new row only the new row is in the datatable, not the existing data.

dim dt as datatable treelist.datasource=dt this is existing item here in any event i want to add the new row in the datatable so that new node is added to the treelist

thanks for your help....

Comment: Can you show how you add the new row in your current code?

Comment: dim dt as datatable
treelist.datasource=dt
this is existing item

here in any event 
i want to add the new row in the datatable 
so that new node is added to the treelist

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to declare a new row and add it to the DataTable as such:

```
'Create the new row
Dim newRow as DataRow = myTable.NewRow

'Add some data to it
newRow("columnName1") = data1
newRow("columnName2") = data2

'Add it to the table
myTable.Rows.Add(newRow)

'Bind the table
treeList.DataSource = dt
treeList.DataBind
```

That should work, just make sure you add the row to the DataTable before you bind it to the TreeView object.